# Convert JSON object list

Tags: javascript, json

i need to convert JSON object to a specific list. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "data_first": {
      "2014-03-14T10:07:31": [
        {
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "name": "name"
        }
      ],
      "2014-03-14T10:08:30": [
        {
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "name": "name"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and what i need is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2014-03-14T10:07:31",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "name": "name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2015-03-14T10:09:31",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "name": "name"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need an array of objects, where the data should be an object value as my example below. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in javascript.

`const data = your json object.data;`

`const result = {data: Object.keys(data.data_first).map(key => ({date: key,  values: data.data_first[key]}))};`